# Null value for extras in onCreate()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle

1. Fetching data into List using JSON and allowing user to select List Item and preparing a folder name by using Items clicked on List, like: Event+Name_Date

   for an example:- Honda Motors_A-05-12-2013
2. Now i am showing Camera along with 2 buttons, namely:- View Gallery & Capture Images
3. Allowing user to capture, and also creating a folder in CaptureImages directory with this name: Honda Motors Event_A-05-12-2013
4. Now once user do click on View Gallery button, showing list of images available in Honda Motors Event_A-05-12-2013 and in a Gallery activity i am also providing back button to go back and capture more Images, but here i am facing problem
5. Whenever user go back and capture images, in place of placing those images into Honda Motors Event_A-05-12-2013 folder, saving it in another folder, folder name like: null Event_null-05-12-2013

**CameraLauncherActivity.java:-**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
            
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        
            mCameraPreview = new PreviewSurface(this, mCamera);
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mCameraPreview);
            
            
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                String value = extras.getString("folder_name");
                Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "folder_name :: " + value);    
            }


            Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
            Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "captureButton :: " + captureButton);
            captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                    Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "mCamera.takePicture :: " + mCamera);                                         
                }
            });
            
            Button viewButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);
            Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "SingleAngelActivityButton :: " + viewButton);
            viewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {             
                  
                    Intent intentNewEvent = new Intent(CameraLauncherActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
                    String event_id = customFolder;
                    intentNewEvent.putExtra("event_id", event_id);
                    startActivity(intentNewEvent);        
                }
            });
            
            cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
             
            // Check if Internet present
            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                // Internet Connection is not present
                alert.showAlertDialog(CameraLauncherActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                        "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
                // stop executing code by return
                return;
            }
        
        // Get event id, angel id
        Intent i = getIntent();
        event_id = i.getStringExtra("event_id");
        angel_id = i.getStringExtra("angel_id");
        
        // calling background thread
        new LoadSingleTrack().execute();
    }
    
    
    
    /**
     * Background Async Task to get single angel information
     * */
    class LoadSingleTrack extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CameraLauncherActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Initializing Camera...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting angel json and parsing
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            
            // post event id, angel id as GET parameters
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("event", event_id));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("angel", angel_id));

            // getting JSON string from URL
            String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_angel, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("Single Track JSON: ", json);

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                if(jObj != null){
                    angel_name = jObj.getString(TAG_ANGEL);
                    event_name = jObj.getString(TAG_EVENT);
                }           

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting angel information
            pDialog.dismiss();
            
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    
                    TextView txt_angel_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.angel_title);
                    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
                
                    txt_angel_name.setText(event_name + " Event_"+ angel_name + "-" + timeStamp);
                    customFolder = txt_angel_name.getText().toString();
                    Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "customFolder :: " + customFolder);
                    
                                 // Change Activity Title with angel title
                    setTitle(angel_name);
                    
                    // folder name
                    mediaStorageDir = new File(
                            Environment
                                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                                    "/CaptureImages/"+ customFolder + "/");
                    
                    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                            Log.d("App", "failed to create directory");                  
                        }
                    }                   
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Helper method to access the camera returns null if it cannot get the
     * camera or does not exist
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        
        Camera camera = null;
        Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "getCameraInstance()Camera:: " + camera);
        try {
            camera = Camera.open(0);
            Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "getCameraInstance()open:: " + camera);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // cannot get camera or does not exist
        }
        return camera;
    }

    PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            camera.startPreview();
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    };
    
    static File getOutputMediaFile() {

        /* yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ */
        timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
        .format(new Date());

        // file name
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
       
        return mediaFile;
    }
```

**Upload.java:-**

```
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
         
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
        
         // Permission StrictMode
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) 
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }       
        TextView textHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEventNameDate);
        textHeading.setText(CameraLauncherActivity.customFolder);
        
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CameraLauncherActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("folder_name", CameraLauncherActivity.customFolder);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

         
        /*** Get Images from SDCard ***/
        ImageList = getSD();
         
        // ListView and imageAdapter
        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lstView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
         
        }
         
         
        private List <String> getSD()
        {
        List <String> it = new ArrayList <String>();
        String string = "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/CaptureImages/";
        File f = new File (string+ CameraLauncherActivity.customFolder+ "/");
        File[] files = f.listFiles ();
         
        for (int i = 0; i <files.length; i++)
        {
        File  file = files[i];
        Log.d("Count",file.getPath());
        it.add (file.getPath());
        }
        return it;
      }
   }
```

**Log:-**

```
12-05 00:12:54.091: I/Choreographer(2284): Skipped 76 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 00:13:08.520: D/CameraLauncherActivity(2284): getCameraInstance()Camera:: null
12-05 00:13:09.380: D/CameraLauncherActivity(2284): getCameraInstance()open:: android.hardware.Camera@41777870
12-05 00:13:09.380: D/CameraLauncherActivity(2284): folder_name :: Honda Motors Event_Angel A-05-12-2013
12-05 00:13:09.390: D/CameraLauncherActivity(2284): captureButton :: android.widget.Button{419fe4d8 VFED..C. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f090004 app:id/btnCapture}
12-05 00:13:09.390: D/CameraLauncherActivity(2284): SingleAngelActivityButton :: android.widget.Button{419b2678 VFED..C. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f090002 app:id/btnView}
12-05 00:13:09.790: I/Choreographer(2284): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 00:13:10.490: I/Choreographer(2284): Skipped 169 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 00:13:13.170: W/System.err(2284): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
12-05 00:13:14.580: I/Choreographer(2284): Skipped 112 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 00:13:14.660: W/System.err(2284):     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
12-05 00:13:15.070: W/System.err(2284):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
12-05 00:13:15.070: W/System.err(2284):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
12-05 00:13:15.070: W/System.err(2284):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
12-05 00:13:15.150: W/System.err(2284):     at com.example.camera.CameraLauncherActivity$LoadSingleTrack.doInBackground(CameraLauncherActivity.java:195)
12-05 00:13:15.280: W/System.err(2284):     at com.example.camera.CameraLauncherActivity$LoadSingleTrack.doInBackground(CameraLauncherActivity.java:1)
12-05 00:13:15.400: W/System.err(2284):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-05 00:13:15.540: W/System.err(2284):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-05 00:13:15.690: W/System.err(2284):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-05 00:13:15.690: W/System.err(2284):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-05 00:13:15.690: W/System.err(2284):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-05 00:13:15.730: I/Choreographer(2284): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 00:13:15.980: I/Choreographer(2284): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 00:13:16.181: W/System.err(2284):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-05 00:13:16.290: I/Choreographer(2284): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 00:13:16.560: I/Choreographer(2284): Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 00:13:21.020: D/CameraLauncherActivity(2284): mCamera.takePicture :: android.hardware.Camera@41777870
12-05 00:13:24.110: D/Count(2284): /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/CaptureImages/null Event_null-05-12-2013/IMG_20131205_001321.jpg
12-05 00:13:25.480: D/dalvikvm(2284): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 147K, 3% free 10392K/10656K, paused 426ms, total 464ms
12-05 00:13:26.340: I/Choreographer(2284): Skipped 493 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

**After adding Log to CustomFolder:-**

```
 12-05 01:32:53.360: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 79 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:32:53.661: D/CameraLauncherActivity(8354): customFolder :: Honda Motors Event_Angel A-05-12-2013
12-05 01:32:53.830: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 124 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:33:01.250: D/CameraLauncherActivity(8354): mCamera.takePicture :: android.hardware.Camera@416f4c90
12-05 01:33:06.540: D/CameraLauncherActivity(8354): mCamera.takePicture :: android.hardware.Camera@416f4c90
12-05 01:33:09.360: D/Count(8354): /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/CaptureImages/Honda Motors Event_Angel A-05-12-2013/IMG_20131205_001237.jpg
12-05 01:33:09.360: D/Count(8354): /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/CaptureImages/Honda Motors Event_Angel A-05-12-2013/IMG_20131205_001239.jpg
12-05 01:33:09.389: D/Count(8354): /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/CaptureImages/Honda Motors Event_Angel A-05-12-2013/IMG_20131205_001240.jpg
12-05 01:33:09.389: D/Count(8354): /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/CaptureImages/Honda Motors Event_Angel A-05-12-2013/IMG_20131205_001242.jpg
12-05 01:33:09.389: D/Count(8354): /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/CaptureImages/Honda Motors Event_Angel A-05-12-2013/IMG_20131205_013302.jpg
12-05 01:33:09.389: D/Count(8354): /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/CaptureImages/Honda Motors Event_Angel A-05-12-2013/IMG_20131205_013306.jpg
12-05 01:33:09.680: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:33:12.000: D/dalvikvm(8354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 224K, 7% free 5431K/5780K, paused 488ms, total 516ms
12-05 01:33:12.161: I/dalvikvm-heap(8354): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.587MB for 1228816-byte allocation
12-05 01:33:12.560: D/dalvikvm(8354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 6629K/6984K, paused 398ms, total 398ms
12-05 01:33:14.320: D/dalvikvm(8354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 57K, 6% free 6621K/6984K, paused 165ms, total 199ms
12-05 01:33:14.340: I/dalvikvm-heap(8354): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.750MB for 1228816-byte allocation
12-05 01:33:14.501: D/dalvikvm(8354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 7821K/8188K, paused 140ms, total 140ms
12-05 01:33:16.050: D/dalvikvm(8354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 4% free 9048K/9392K, paused 161ms, total 162ms
12-05 01:33:17.270: D/dalvikvm(8354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 34K, 4% free 10261K/10596K, paused 227ms, total 280ms
12-05 01:33:17.960: D/dalvikvm(8354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 34K, 3% free 11474K/11800K, paused 132ms, total 137ms
12-05 01:33:18.550: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 2287 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:33:22.031: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 81 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:03.100: D/CameraLauncherActivity(8354): getCameraInstance()Camera:: null
12-05 01:50:03.980: D/CameraLauncherActivity(8354): getCameraInstance()open:: android.hardware.Camera@41968f50
12-05 01:50:03.980: D/CameraLauncherActivity(8354): folder_name :: Honda Motors Event_Angel A-05-12-2013
12-05 01:50:03.980: D/CameraLauncherActivity(8354): captureButton :: android.widget.Button{41999820 VFED..C. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f090004 app:id/btnCapture}
12-05 01:50:03.980: D/CameraLauncherActivity(8354): SingleAngelActivityButton :: android.widget.Button{41999298 VFED..C. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f090002 app:id/btnView}
12-05 01:50:04.801: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 124 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:07.900: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 134 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:08.961: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:09.252: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:09.501: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:09.721: W/System.err(8354): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
12-05 01:50:09.780: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:10.080: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:10.500: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 110 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:10.771: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:11.061: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 73 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:11.361: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:11.550: W/System.err(8354):     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
12-05 01:50:11.550: W/System.err(8354):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
12-05 01:50:11.580: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:11.590: W/System.err(8354):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:154)
12-05 01:50:11.870: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:12.091: W/System.err(8354):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
12-05 01:50:12.091: W/System.err(8354):     at com.example.camera.CameraLauncherActivity$LoadSingleTrack.doInBackground(CameraLauncherActivity.java:195)
12-05 01:50:12.091: W/System.err(8354):     at com.example.camera.CameraLauncherActivity$LoadSingleTrack.doInBackground(CameraLauncherActivity.java:1)
12-05 01:50:12.100: W/System.err(8354):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-05 01:50:12.100: W/System.err(8354):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-05 01:50:12.140: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:12.360: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:12.370: W/System.err(8354):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-05 01:50:12.620: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:12.831: W/System.err(8354):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-05 01:50:12.831: W/System.err(8354):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-05 01:50:12.840: W/System.err(8354):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-05 01:50:12.890: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:13.200: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 82 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:13.460: D/CameraLauncherActivity(8354): customFolder :: null Event_null-05-12-2013
12-05 01:50:13.460: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:17.000: D/CameraLauncherActivity(8354): mCamera.takePicture :: android.hardware.Camera@41968f50
12-05 01:50:18.580: D/CameraLauncherActivity(8354): mCamera.takePicture :: android.hardware.Camera@41968f50
12-05 01:50:21.241: D/Count(8354): /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/CaptureImages/null Event_null-05-12-2013/IMG_20131205_001321.jpg
12-05 01:50:21.241: D/Count(8354): /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/CaptureImages/null Event_null-05-12-2013/IMG_20131205_015017.jpg
12-05 01:50:21.250: D/Count(8354): /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/CaptureImages/null Event_null-05-12-2013/IMG_20131205_015018.jpg
12-05 01:50:21.530: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:22.900: D/dalvikvm(8354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 180K, 3% free 12821K/13128K, paused 589ms, total 619ms
12-05 01:50:24.810: D/dalvikvm(8354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 56K, 3% free 14012K/14332K, paused 626ms, total 662ms
12-05 01:50:26.550: D/dalvikvm(8354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 34K, 2% free 15225K/15536K, paused 569ms, total 570ms
12-05 01:50:26.800: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 1372 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-05 01:50:28.980: I/Choreographer(8354): Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Check the `folder_name` in CameraCapture.java

Comment: yeah getting correct folder name as needed

Comment: @MikeM. ok let me know if i am coming back to camera activity and using onResume() method, is that ok?

Comment: No log the folder_name

Comment: @Arju see my updated question with code

Comment: Could you add a log in CameraLauncherActivity.java in post execute, just log and see the value in the variable customFolder. That should make a few things clearer

Comment: @AdnanMulla check now

Comment: Exactly what I thought ! Your variables event_name and angel_name which are set based on response from the server are null. Check to see if your server response is proper and is returning you the values properly.                                                 Also the log shows : org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of  Your JSON response or parsing is wrong. You need to check the parser or the response from the server.

Comment: @AdnanMulla yeah i agree with you, but also try to understand my problem, please read point 4 & 5. whenever i do tap on back button in gallery activity then i just need to keep existing folder name and have to store all images in that folder

Comment: Ah my bad! I understand what your trying to do, yes the problem is the second time when you go back the activity is re-created and the server  returns null, you need to have a static boolean field which will help you identify if this is the first time user has started this activity or has the user come back to take more pics in same folder. If user has come back to take more pics you need to set customFolder variable to the value you got from intent else set it to the response got from server. That should solve your problem.

Comment: @AdnanMulla i am facing this problem for last few days, please try to resolve

Comment: @AdnanMulla I am getting I may award my bounty after 19 hours, so will bount you tomorrow.. sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find updated code here for CameraLauncherActivity.java :

```
static boolean isReturning = false;
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        mCameraPreview = new PreviewSurface(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mCameraPreview);


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String value = extras.getString("folder_name");
            isReturning = extras.getBoolean("isReturning");
            Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "folder_name :: " + value);    
        }


        Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
        Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "captureButton :: " + captureButton);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "mCamera.takePicture :: " + mCamera);                                         
            }
        });

        Button viewButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnView);
        Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "SingleAngelActivityButton :: " + viewButton);
        viewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {             

                Intent intentNewEvent = new Intent(CameraLauncherActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
                String event_id = customFolder;
                intentNewEvent.putExtra("event_id", event_id);
                startActivity(intentNewEvent);        
            }
        });

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if Internet present
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(CameraLauncherActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

    // Get event id, angel id
    Intent i = getIntent();
    event_id = i.getStringExtra("event_id");
    angel_id = i.getStringExtra("angel_id");

    // calling background thread
    new LoadSingleTrack().execute();
}



/**
 * Background Async Task to get single angel information
 * */
class LoadSingleTrack extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CameraLauncherActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Initializing Camera...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting angel json and parsing
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // post event id, angel id as GET parameters
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("event", event_id));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("angel", angel_id));

        // getting JSON string from URL
        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_angel, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("Single Track JSON: ", json);

        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            if(jObj != null){
                angel_name = jObj.getString(TAG_ANGEL);
                event_name = jObj.getString(TAG_EVENT);
            }           

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting angel information
        pDialog.dismiss();

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                TextView txt_angel_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.angel_title);
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());

                txt_angel_name.setText(event_name + " Event_"+ angel_name + "-" + timeStamp);

     if(!isReturning){
         customFolder = txt_angel_name.getText().toString();
     }else{
         customFolder = extras.getString("folder_name");
     }
                Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "customFolder :: " + customFolder);

                             // Change Activity Title with angel title
                setTitle(angel_name);

                // folder name
                mediaStorageDir = new File(
                        Environment
                                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                                "/CaptureImages/"+ customFolder + "/");

                if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                    if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                        Log.d("App", "failed to create directory");                  
                    }
                }                   
            }
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Helper method to access the camera returns null if it cannot get the
 * camera or does not exist
 * 
 * @return
 */
private Camera getCameraInstance() {

    Camera camera = null;
    Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "getCameraInstance()Camera:: " + camera);
    try {
        camera = Camera.open(0);
        Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "getCameraInstance()open:: " + camera);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // cannot get camera or does not exist
    }
    return camera;
}

PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        camera.startPreview();
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
};

static File getOutputMediaFile() {

    /* yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ */
    timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
    .format(new Date());

    // file name
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
            + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Now under Upload.java :

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CameraLauncherActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("folder_name", CameraLauncherActivity.customFolder);
            i.putExtras("isReturning", true);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

That's it. Now it should work as needed!  Hope this helps

Comment: having problem here:  customFolder = extras.getString("folder_name");  extras can not be resolved

Comment: @AbrahimNeil Change `extras` to `getIntent().getExtras()`. Use proper error checking as you're neither checking for `null` extras, nor checking if the `extras bundle` contains a specific `key-value` pair.

Comment: @AbrahimNeil If nothing else, declare `Bundle extras;` as global. And change `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();` to `extras = getIntent().getExtras();`. The error checking problem still remains though.

Comment: +1 thanks a lot... you are genius, just want to know why we are using i.putExtra("isReturning", true);

Comment: Thats just a variable that tells us that the user is coming back to take more pics so don't create a new folder instead use the same folder !

Comment: @AbrahimNeil By the way, this solution can be improved. When the user returns to `CameraLauncherActivity`, you already have a `folder_name`. So, there's no need to execute the `AsyncTask`. If the `extras` bundle doesn't contain `event_id` or `angel_id`, don't launch the AsyncTask and use `folder_name` instead. Right now, you're performing a network operation for no reason.

Comment: Yes ideally that would be the way to do it ! +1

Comment: @AdnanMulla need a small help, not getting list of captured images on my Samsung mobile, if i have only single image in a List then able to view list, but if in my list i have multiple images or more than 1 then i am getting Unfortunately App has stopped, error only on device, working fine on Emulator

Comment: @user2558882 can you help me? not getting list of captured images on my Samsung mobile, if i have only single image in a List then able to view list, but if in my list i have multiple images or more than 1 then i am getting Unfortunately App has stopped, error only on device, working fine on Emulator

Comment: @AbrahimNeil Please post the Logcat output from when the app crashes on the Samsung device. And which `ListView` are you talking about? Is it `lstView` from `Upload.java`? Also include the `ImageAdapter` code.

Comment: @user2558882 Hi i am testing my app on Samsung Galaxy Camera - getting Unfortunately App has stopped, first of all how to see the Logcat output from Camera when the app crashes, yeah i am talking about lstView from Upload.java and yes it also includes ImageAdapter.java.. help me, need to send apk to client for testing

Comment: @user2558882 ignore above texts and messages, please browse this link: http://pastebin.com/PZKpZZQb and you can contact me: abrahim.neil@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your issue appears to be the extras from the getIntent are null. This is because  the extras are not saved when the activity is restarted with a new intent such as the one you are seeing. You should be saving your "persistent" data `onSaveInstanceState` and reading it `onCreate`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    Bundle bundle = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState : getIntent().getExtras();
    mFolderName = bundle.getStringExtra("folder_name");
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  savedInstanceState.putLong("folder_name", mFolderName);
}
```

Comment: The code I have posted is two parts. Please try to understand. I'm confident it will solve your problem.

Comment: yeah i also agree with you, that's why i tried your code many times but still getting same issue, check my updated code above

Comment: @AbrahimNeil no offense but your post is all over the place... You have two onResume methods in CameraCapture.java and CameraCapture.java [more code] plus there is a class CameraLauncherActivity where CameraLauncherActivity.customFolder appears to be a static property. It would probably help to get it cleaned up so it's more obvious what your problem is.